# how to append custom metabox field with the ACF custom fields id in wordpress development

Tags: plugin-development

I am new to wordpress development, I have installed Advanced Custom Field plugin in my project and created a two text fields Name & Email and also I have created a plugin which will create a metabox with text box inside the Post. Now in the post I will get the custom fields Name & Email and next to that my custom metabox will come, but I have to append my metabox next to the Name field, that is in between the Name field and Email field. My metabox code as below. Please anyone help me

```
//Creating the custom meta box
function my_notice_meta_box() {
    //$post_type = ['post','acf-field-group'];
    add_meta_box(
        'my-notice',
        __( 'My Notice', 'mymetabox' ),
        'my_notice_meta_box_callback',
        'post'     
    );

}
add_action('add_meta_boxes','my_notice_meta_box'); 

//To display meta box input field
function my_notice_meta_box_callback() {       
    
    ?>
 
    <p>
        <label><strong><?php _e("Notice") ?></strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="meta-text" id="meta-text" value="" />
    </p>
 
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ACF automatically adds a meta box, so you shouldn't need to add a custom meta box with your fields. Be sure to confirm the 'Location' settings on your ACF field group if it isn't showing up. (You can also add multiple Field Groups if you want ACF fields to show up in different locations for the same post-type).

However, if you really need to manage ACF fields on your own, you can refer to their docs to obtain the field information via `get_field_object` and to manually update the field via `update_field`.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/